# Considerations when retaining uploaded file's original filename

Tags: php, security, file-upload

I am trying to convert our uploaded filenames from an unreadable pile of files to an organized and human-readable structure of files. I am wondering if there are any additional security measures I need to take to safe this type of system.

To give a brief overview, the current system uploads files, generates a random filename, and allows the files to be accessed only through a download script (I have no need to serve the files directly to the browser).

In short, I'd like to implement a WebDav system and would think the easiest solution would be to store uploaded files with their original name (separated into different folders).

Thank you

Edit: To clarify, **I'd like to retain the filename as much as possible**, but I'd obviously need to at least sanitize the filenames first. I've considered chmod-ing the containing folder to prevent execution (a folder located outside of the web directory). **What, in addition, am I not considering**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In short, I'd like to implement a WebDav system and would think the easiest solution would be to store uploaded files with their original name

This is pretty wide question but to make answer short: **NEVER TRUST USER PROVIDED DATA**. You must always do server side validation and sanitization, otherwise you will be hacked sooner or later.

Original file name is sent by client, so it can be anything. Here's some ideas of what I'd try to send you as "original" file names knowing you are so
carefree: `../../../../etc/passwd` or `../../config/db.php`. Handle as-it-comes. Enjoy :)

**EDIT**

> I  should have mentioned things I've considered -- sanitizing filenames

Sanitized file name is not an `original file name` any more. However there's approach you could consider here to meed your goal and still stay safe. You could validate/sanitize original file names and if after that it still the same as it came from user, you can keep the file and retain the original name. If it is not, then you should reject the file upload as whole. At the end fo the day  you will have only files that you can allow to be accessed with original file names via other API/interfaces.

**EDIT**

> I've considered chmod-ing the containing folder to prevent execution

This is bad security. You should rather keep files in the folder that is not accessible directly instead.

Comment: I should have mentioned things I've considered -- sanitizing filenames, chmod-ing the containing folders

Comment: Sanitized file name is not `original file name`. You asked about retaining original (which means unaltered) names and I address that.

Comment: You are talking about storing outside of the web directory, correct? If not, where would you suggest?

Comment: Yes, so you cannot directly request the file.

Answer (score 0):

From [How to Securely Allow Users to Upload Files](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/10/how-securely-allow-users-upload-files):

> #### Always Store Uploaded Files Outside of the Document Root
>
> If your website is `example.com` and when a visitor accesses this website in their browser, the script located at `/home/example/public_html/index.php` is executed, then you should not be storing the files that users have uploaded in `/home/example/public_html/` or any of its subdirectories. A good candidate, instead, would be `/home/example/uploaded/`.

...

> - Instead of storing the file at `/home/example/uploaded/some/directories/user_provided.file`, store all relevant metadata in a database record (while taking care to [prevent SQL injection vulnerabilities](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/05/preventing-sql-injection-in-php-applications-easy-and-definitive-guide)) and use a [random filename](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/07/how-safely-generate-random-strings-and-integers-in-php) for the actual filesystem storage.

This does three things:

1. It guarantees that your user's file will never be *executed* as a script. They get read-only access whether they like it or not. (No reverse shells!)
2. It prevents the user from controlling the filename, to prevent security-critical files from being overwritten.
3. It allows you to retain as much metadata about each file as you'd like without sacrificing security.

If you need a real implementation to reference, here are two from a CMS that I'm developing:

- [Uploading files](https://github.com/paragonie/airship/blob/62454f41cbb07da3721202d9fd4564b79f0ac96c/src/Cabin/Bridge/Blueprint/Files.php#L642)
- [Serving files](https://github.com/paragonie/airship/blob/62454f41cbb07da3721202d9fd4564b79f0ac96c/src/Cabin/Hull/Landing/PublicFiles.php#L24)