# Save File with original filename when using the actix-web-Framework to upload a File on a webserver in Rust

Tags: rust, file-upload, actix-web

I'm creating a webserver in Rust using the actix-web Framework. Currently I'm working on the Fileupload and for this im using actix-multipart.

In the official Actix-Documentation there is an example for it:

```
use std::cell::Cell;
use std::fs;
use std::io::Write;

use actix_multipart::{Field, Multipart, MultipartError};
use actix_web::{error, middleware, web, App, Error, HttpResponse, HttpServer};
use futures::future::{err, Either};
use futures::{Future, Stream};

pub fn save_file(field: Field) -> impl Future<Item = i64, Error = Error> {
    let file_path_string = "upload.png";
    let file = match fs::File::create(file_path_string) {
        Ok(file) => file,
        Err(e) => return Either::A(err(error::ErrorInternalServerError(e))),
    };
    Either::B(
        field
            .fold((file, 0i64), move |(mut file, mut acc), bytes| {
                // fs operations are blocking, we have to execute writes
                // on threadpool
                web::block(move || {
                    file.write_all(bytes.as_ref()).map_err(|e| {
                        println!("file.write_all failed: {:?}", e);
                        MultipartError::Payload(error::PayloadError::Io(e))
                    })?;
                    acc += bytes.len() as i64;
                    Ok((file, acc))
                })
                .map_err(|e: error::BlockingError<MultipartError>| {
                    match e {
                        error::BlockingError::Error(e) => e,
                        error::BlockingError::Canceled => MultipartError::Incomplete,
                    }
                })
            })
            .map(|(_, acc)| acc)
            .map_err(|e| {
                println!("save_file failed, {:?}", e);
                error::ErrorInternalServerError(e)
            }),
    )
}

pub fn upload(
    multipart: Multipart,
    counter: web::Data<Cell<usize>>,
) -> impl Future<Item = HttpResponse, Error = Error> {
    counter.set(counter.get() + 1);
    println!("{:?}", counter.get());

    multipart
        .map_err(error::ErrorInternalServerError)
        .map(|field| save_file(field).into_stream())
        .flatten()
        .collect()
        .map(|sizes| HttpResponse::Ok().json(sizes))
        .map_err(|e| {
            println!("failed: {}", e);
            e
        })
}

fn index() -> HttpResponse {
    let html = r#"<html>
        <head><title>Upload Test</title></head>
        <body>
            <form target="/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input type="file" name="file"/>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit"></button>
            </form>
        </body>
    </html>"#;

    HttpResponse::Ok().body(html)
}

fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {

    HttpServer::new(|| {
        App::new()
            .data(Cell::new(0usize))
            .wrap(middleware::Logger::default())
            .service(
                web::resource("/")
                    .route(web::get().to(index))
                    .route(web::post().to_async(upload)),
            )
    })
    .bind("127.0.0.1:8080")?
    .run()
}
```

This would be a minimal working implementation for it and works good so far. But as you can see the filepathstring is a custom string which renames the file on the server to upload.png (`let file_path_string = "upload.png"`)

So is there a simple way to retrieve the original filename and use it as filename for the uploaded file on the server?

Comment: Please note that this is **not** a good idea. This can lead to serious security issues. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/36791160 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/9923416

Comment: Field type provides content_disposition() method. https://docs.rs/actix-multipart/0.1.0-beta.4/actix_multipart/struct.Field.html#method.content_disposition

Comment: *and works good so far* — Does that mean that you've solved your previous question ([Actix-Web reports “App data is not configured” when processing a file upload](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56117273/155423))?

Comment: I found a way around it but not by using the AppState Struct as I mentioned in the my previous question. So the workaround is not an ideal solution and my question is not solved yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The content_disposition() method as suggested by NK is potentially what you are after here. So you could perhaps replace:

```
let file_path_string = "upload.png";
```

with something like:

```
let file_path_string = match field.content_disposition().unwrap().get_filename() {
    Some(filename) => filename.replace(' ', "_").to_string(),
    None => return Either::A(err(error::ErrorInternalServerError("Couldn't read the filename.")))
}
```